# Not a Ubuntu question, but a Linux query in general: MS-DOS like OS for Linux?

Tags: command-line, windows, prompt

I'm looking for a Linux OS that runs fully through the terminal, kind of like MS-DOS. I'm using a 100 Mb device that I intend to use for only basic functions like transfer files from various drives and stuff.

Sorry if I'm vague or making no sense, Linux is a whole new thing to me, I'm three days Linux fresh.

Comment: We only accept Ubuntu related questions. You should visit U&L with questions like this

Comment: Go to [this page](http://www.freedos.org/), and forget about Linux DOS alternative. You can find a live cd image in there if you are as sharp as you sound. You can run Ubuntu/Xubuntu in text-mode only too, just press Ctrl+Alt+F1 key combination after install.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is based on Debian and Debian can run fully on the terminal.  Just choose not to install X11 and you will get a command-line only version of Linux.

For a lengthy list of linux distributions specifically designed to be low-memory, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution).

[BasicLinux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/baslinux/) is particularly small: it can run on as little as 3MB of RAM and is so small that it can fit in 2.8 MB (two floppies!).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/) it's a small Linux distro that can run in as little as 10 MB of RAM, it's also pretty customizable, check out the [Intro page](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/intro.html) for more information.

you would want to download the Core ISO or CorePlus since you say you're new to Linux. Download are available from [here](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/downloads.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu can do this! (This is Ask Ubuntu, after all.)

For a really lightweight version of Ubuntu, you can check out [Ubuntu Core](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) which may need some configuration. For something that runs command-line only out of the box, but isn't as lightweight, you can try [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).